# javascript RegEx detect only spaces \s

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect spaces on textarea
my code is following

```
textarea.value.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
```

but it detects all whitespaces and I want to detect only spaces...

is any solution??

Comment: Use `/ /g` maybe? Should work.

Comment: If you don't want to use whitespace literally in a regex you can also use `/\u0020/g`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```javascript
textarea.value.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
// that's a space ------^
```

Comment: +1 for ascii-art arrows.

Comment: @maxART Instead of thanking him in a comment, accept his answer. :)

Comment: I can not now :) I will after 6 minute :)

Answer (score 3):

use a literal space, like so:

```
textarea.value.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
textarea.value.replace(/[ ]/g, '&nbsp;');
```